# Нужны ли тут запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, с предложением: "Жалюзи, как заменитель занавесей, были известны людям очень давно". По идее, "жалюзи в качестве заменителя занавесей", значит, запятая не нужна. Или все-таки нужна?
Заранее спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 3):

Конечно, здесь значение "в качестве", поэтому запятая не нужна

Answer (score 0):

не нужна, т.к. тут в значении качества